# Cosmos DB - Spring Data - Find By Collection Contains

Tags: spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

I have an entity as follows:

```
@Document(collection = "MetadataMerchants")
public class MetadataMerchant {

        public String id;

        @PartitionKey
        public String name;

        @JsonProperty("descriptors")
        public List<String> descriptors;
}
```

and my Repository is as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface MetadataMerchantRepository extends CosmosRepository<MetadataMerchant, String> {

    List<MetadataMerchant> findByName(String name);

    List<MetadataMerchant> findByDescriptorsContains(List<String> descriptors);
}
```

`findByName` is working as expected, in other words this returns a single result:

```
repository.findByName("Test Merchant");
```

I want to be able to query `MetadataMerchant`s that has a specific `descriptor`. My attempt with `findByDescriptorsContains(List<String> descriptors)` does not seem to be working, it always returns an empty result.

Using `spring-data-cosmosdb` and Spring Data, how do I query entities by values in a collection? I want to be able to find all `MetadataMerchant`s with `descriptors` containing a specific value..

In Azure Cosmos DB Data Explorer, the following query works:

```
SELECT * FROM MetadataMerchants m WHERE EXISTS(SELECT VALUE d FROM d IN m.descriptors WHERE d = 'a-descriptor-here')
```

I stole the idea from MongoDB examples (see `List<Person> findBySkillsContains(List<String> skills);`)

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Person.java
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/PersonRepository.java)

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ?

Comment: @AlwaysanewComer No.